# docker-compose.ymlのボリュームについて

Tags: docker, docker-compose

> - ホスト側のフォルダAをコンテナのフォルダBにマウントする
> - コンテナのフォルダB直下のフォルダCを名前付きボリュームに保存する

上記をdocker-compose.ymlで設定したところ、ホスト側のフォルダA直下にフォルダCが表示されますが、フォルダCが空になっています（コンテナ側フォルダCにはファイルがあります）。
何故ホスト側フォルダCは空なのでしょうか。

```
services:
  app:
    images: php
    volumes:
      - フォルダA：フォルダB
      - volumeC：フォルダC
volumes:
  volumeC:
```

Answer (score 1):

- フォルダA：フォルダB という指定の仕方は「バインドマウント」と呼ばれ、ローカルのフォルダAとコンテナのフォルダBをリンクしてくれます。

一方で、自分で作成したボリュームの場合はバインドマウントが行われないため、Docker Volumeという領域でデータを永続化するために使います。この場合、ローカルのファイルシステムとのリンクが行われないので、手元のフォルダCにはファイルが保存されないどころか、リンクも行われません。